# How to connect to Django from Spring

Tags: django, spring, webserver

I'm trying to find a way of sending data to my web server on Spring framework from Django which controls actions of tensorflow.

If Spring server send a request, is it possible to send a output from Django?

If you have experiences like this, please give me some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make an HTTP request to your Django server, respond with JSON, and then parse that JSON into a Java class using a library like jackson.

Alternatively you can use a shared database where Spring simply uses JDBC to access the data you are trying to reach.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it.